# A sequence $f_k:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $\int f_k=0 \quad \forall k\in \mathbb N $ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f_k \equiv1$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, pointwise-convergence

Find a sequence of Lebesgue Integrable functions $f_k:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that
$\int f_k=0 \quad \forall k\in \mathbb N $ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f_k \equiv1$.

---

My guess is
 $$ f_k(x) = sign(x-k)
$$
Then integral is $0$ by symmetry and $f_k$ converges to 1. Is it right?
Can you give more examples?

Comment: Lebesgue measurable? Then what is $\Omega$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions are supposed to be Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb R$, then your example, whose absolute value is $1$ everywhere, is not Lebesgue integrable.

An example that illustrates the principle would be
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in [-n, n] \\
-2n & x \in [-(n+1),-n) \\
0 & \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Is $sign$ not Lebesgue integrable because $\int_\mathbb R |sign()| \  dx = \infty$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Omega=[0,1]$, then you can set 
$$
f_k(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \in [\frac{1}{k}, 1] \\
1-k & x \in (0,\frac{1}{k}) \\
1 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$